# What is melting / boiling from the statistical viewpoint?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

Microscopically, solids are usually described as "completely ordered" and "strongly bound", liquids "somewhat ordered", and gases "unbound" and "disordered". Thermodynamics predicts that the transition between solid, liquid, and gas of a pure substance will happen at a constant temperature given a fixed pressure.

So my question is:

1. Why would the (majority of) molecules go from "strongly bound" to "loosely bound" uniformly at the same temperature?
2. Can we distinguish between a bunch of molecules in a solid and in a liquid without calculating the mean kinetic energy?
3. If we could calculate the interaction between molecules accurately, can we predict the boiling point / melting point without carrying out any sort of dynamic simulation?

Thanks!

Comment: Thermodynamics doesn't quite say that; the statements apply at equilibrium.  Oft times processes take place farcfrom equilibrium,  hence one part is melting while further away it is not. The dynamic question is: what is the range of current events? How well connected is atom x to it's closest neighbors?  To it's further neighbors?  How are their motions correlated? Thermodynamic principles do not give us the equations of state; these are experimental, but can be calculated through complex simulation.